# ORDER BY multiple variables

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find a way to display my users in a specific order:

- First, the trending female (bool)
- Then, the most recent registered female (date_registered)
- Then, the trending male (bool)
- Then, the most recent registered male (date_registered)

```
id | sex    | trending | date_registered
---+--------+----------+----------------
1  | male   | 1        | 29-04-2020
2  | male   | 1        | 28-04-2020
3  | male   | 0        | 27-04-2020
4  | female | 1        | 26-04-2020
5  | female | 1        | 25-04-2020
6  | female | 0        | 24-04-2020
7  | female | 0        | 23-04-2020
8  | male   | 1        | 22-04-2020
9  | male   | 0        | 21-04-2020
```

So far I'm able to display the trending users, then the most recent registered user using this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
ORDER BY users.trending DESC, users.date_registered DESC
```

But I need to find a way to separate the males and females.

This is the order of the wanted output:

```
id | sex    | trending | date_registered | order_wanted
---+--------+----------+-----------------+-------------
1  | male   | 1        | 29-04-2020      | 5
2  | male   | 1        | 28-04-2020      | 6
3  | male   | 0        | 27-04-2020      | 8
4  | female | 1        | 26-04-2020      | 1
5  | female | 1        | 25-04-2020      | 2
6  | female | 0        | 24-04-2020      | 3
7  | female | 0        | 23-04-2020      | 4
8  | male   | 1        | 22-04-2020      | 7
9  | male   | 0        | 21-04-2020      | 9
```

Answer (score 0):

If I follow the logic correctly, your conditions reduce to three sorting keys:

- Trending first
- Then gender
- Then date_registered

You can assign the ordering column using `row_number()`:

```
select u.*,
       row_number() over (order by trending desc, gender asc, date_registered desc) as ord
from users u
```

Note that `order` is a really bad name for a column because it is a SQL keyword.

If you don't want a separate column, then just use the `order by` for the entire query:

```
order by trending desc, gender asc, date_registered desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below query,

```
SELECT *
FROM users
ORDER BY date_registered desc, sex, trending;
```